# Why doesn't the regex [A-Za-z]* work as expected?

Tags: regex, oracle

Why doesn't `regexp_substr(data,'[A-Za-z]*')` work as expected?

Table data:

```
2014 CODE-B
```

Expected output:

```
CODE
```

Comment: Try `regexp_substr(data,'[A-Za-z]+')`.

Comment: You should answer @AmalMurali it works. I was preparing a sqlfiddle to answer. Since you did it first here. go on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` makes the whole expression optional, so the first match is the empty string.

You'll want to use something like this (the `i` makes it case-insensitive, so you don't need `a-z`):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(mycolumn, '[A-Z]+', 1, 1, 'i') FROM mytable;
```

Comment: +1. The Regex101 Debugger is also very helpful. Here's how the matching is done: [OP's original regex](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SxbPE.png), [yours](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xa6vS.png).

Comment: Hey Sudakhar my comment was in reply to a comment by another guy, Avinash, who said that it didn't work... He deleted his own answer and his comment. As I'm sure you realize, the parameters in `REGEX_SUBSTR` dictate where we attempt to match and which match number we return. For instance, if you knew that your string always look like `ABC2014 CODE-B`, to retrieve `CODE` you would want the second match (using the same regex) so you would use `...'[A-Z]+', 1, 2, 'i'`

Comment: @Sudhakar: Note that I used "*may*". As zx81 says in the above comment, I was just responding to another commenter above (who appears to have deleted their answer and comment) :)